# Created a custom framework in swift and app is getting crashed

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks

The only error it is throwing is "dyld[1233]: missing symbol called". The digits inside braces get changed all the time. The code I have checked on the App side works perfectly without any crashes. But the same code when I migrate to SDK (with public specifier) it crashes.

Please help me, This is my first time working on SDK.

Note: - The agenda of SDK is to pair with the BLE device (via Bluetooth) and update its firmware(DFU).

The pairing code in SDK works well, but while updating the DFU of the device, the app crashes.

Things which I tried,

1. General-> Frameworks, Libraries,Embed contents -> embed and sign
2. Cross checked whether any issue from the code side, seems it is an SDK issue
3. Rearranged the order of custom wayband SDK under General-> Frameworks, Libraries, Embed contents

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you fix this?